# Reading a field in a line divided by tabs

Tags: java, string, bufferedreader

I have a text file of lacs of line and a single line is in the format as follows:

```
a | b | c(may contain url) | d(may contain url)
```

I want to extract the complete text in the last field i.e. `d` from the line.

How can I do it once I have read the line using BufferedReader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way is as follows:

```
package eu.webfarmr.stackoverflow;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * The goal of this class is to read lines from a text file which contain
 * vertical bars and extract the fields separated by these tabs
 * 
 * @author djob
 * 
 */
public class FileLACSReader {

    private final static String SEPARATOR = "\\|";

    /**
     * 
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        List<String> lines = readContents("etc/sampleInput.txt");
        for (String input : lines) {
            String[] splitContent = input.split(SEPARATOR);
            for (String field : splitContent) {
                System.out.println(field);
            }
        }
    }

    public static List<String> readContents(String file)
            throws FileNotFoundException {
        List<String> textLines = new ArrayList<String>();
        FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File(file));
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(stream);
        try {
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                textLines.add(scanner.nextLine());
            }
        } finally {
            scanner.close();
        }
        return textLines;

    }

}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the String.split method:

```
    String line = "a | b | c(may contain url) | d(may contain url)";
    String[] parts = line.split("\\|");
    String lastPart = parts[parts.length - 1];
    System.out.println(lastPart);
```

Answer (score 1):

lins.substring(line.lastIndexOf(x));
line.lastIndexOf(x) will return the index of the last found x symbol (in this case x is a tab (\t)) and you can get the substring of your line from that index.
if your last field also contains that symbol you should use regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You cab store the text you read from the file into a `String` and than you can do:

```
String str = "a | b | c(may contain url) | d(may contain url)";
int x = str.lastIndexOf("|");
String str1 = str.substring(x+2);
System.out.println(str1);
```